# Getting ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement when loading Fuse ESB

Tags: java, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am new to ESB and am struggling to get it going.  Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direct to resolve this issue.

**My Environment:**
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit)
JDK: 1.7.0_51 (64bit)
Fuse: JBoss Fuse 6.0

**I am getting the following exception:**

```
ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement: org.osgi.framework.startlevel;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.0", org.osgi.framework.wiring;uses:="org.osgi.resource,org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.hooks.service;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver;uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring";version="1.0", org.osgi.framework.launch;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.namespace;uses:="org.osgi.resource";version="1.0", org.osgi.framework;version="1.7",org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving;uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring";version="1.0",org.osgi.resource;version="1.0",org.osgi.service.url;version="1.0",org.osgi.service.startlevel;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1",org.osgi.service.packageadmin;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.2",org.osgi.service.url;version="1.0", org.osgi.util.tracker;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.5.1", org.apache.felix.framework.monitor;version="1.0", org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot;version="2.3.0.redhat-60024", org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal;version="2.3.0.redhat-60024", org.apache.karaf.version;version="2.3.0.redhat-60024", org.apache.xalan.extensions; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.compiler; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.cmdline.getopt; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.util; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.transformer; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.processor; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.lib; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.trace; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.compiler.util; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.templates; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.runtime; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xslt; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.lib.sql; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.runtime.output; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.dom; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.client; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.cmdline; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.serialize; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.res; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.dtm; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.sax2dtm; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.dom2dtm; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.res; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.serializer; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.serializer.utils; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.utils.res; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.utils; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.functions; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.jaxp; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.patterns; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.objects; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.res; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.axes; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.compiler; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.operations; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.domapi; version="2.7.1", org.apache.html.dom; version="2.11.0", org.apache.wml.dom; version="2.11.0", org.apache.wml; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.parsers; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.models; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xni.parser; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.util; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.dom3.as; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath.regex; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xni; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.msg; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.util; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.util; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.dom; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.dom.events; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xs; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.io; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xpointer; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xinclude; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xs.datatypes; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.identity; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.models; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xni.grammars; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.validation; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xml.serialize; version="2.11.0", ,org.apache.karaf.branding (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.)

**The log file has this message which keeps repeating:**

Mar 20, 2014 10:51:20 PM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock

INFO: locking

Mar 20, 2014 10:51:21 PM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock

INFO: locking

Mar 20, 2014 10:51:22 PM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock

INFO: locking
```

Appreciate any help that I can get.  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when `org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock` is used to implement a simple master-slave failover deployment. More details can be found [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Configuring_and_Running_JBoss_Fuse/files/ESBRuntimeFailoverFileLock.html).

If an already another FUSE ESB instance is running, then the second started instance is waiting until the first process is stopped. If you stop the first instance, the second instance will start and get the lock and the log entries will disappear.

Master and slave instance must refer to the same lock file in the file system. If this is not possible as master and slave are on different hosts, then `org.apache.karaf.main.DefaultJDBCLock` can be used.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.  I can't see the other instance running in the active processes.  Is there something obvious I am missing?  I even restarted the machine and tried from scratch but no luck.

Comment: I have figured it out.. it was because it was in a restricted area and needed elevated privileges.  Appreciate your help though I need to create a failover deployment eventually so you have pointed me in the right direction.