# I'm can't start an out of the box instance of RedHat Fuse

Tags: java, jbossfuse, karaf

On two different computers, I cannot get RedHat Fuse 6.1 to start.  I'm new to the intricacies of OSGi and Fuse, so the following doesn't make sense to me.  However, I'm told this product *should* work out of the box, which is what I tried to do.

The following is a console redirect for what I'm getting.  The log file is even shorter.

Please wait while JBoss Fuse is loading...

> ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement:
>   org.osgi.framework.startlevel;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.0",
>   org.osgi.framework.wiring;uses:="org.osgi.resource,org.osgi.framework";version="1.1",
>   org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1",
>   org.osgi.framework.hooks.service;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1",
>   org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver;uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring";version="1.0",
>   org.osgi.framework.launch;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1",
>   org.osgi.framework.namespace;uses:="org.osgi.resource";version="1.0",
>   org.osgi.framework;version="1.7",org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving;uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring";version="1.0",org.osgi.resource;version="1.0",org.osgi.service.url;version="1.0",org.osgi.service.startlevel;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1",org.osgi.service.packageadmin;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.2",org.osgi.service.url;version="1.0",
>   org.osgi.util.tracker;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.5.1",
>   org.apache.felix.framework.monitor;version="1.0",
>   org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot;version="2.3.0.redhat-610379",
>   org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal;version="2.3.0.redhat-610379",
>   org.apache.karaf.version;version="2.3.0.redhat-610379",
>   org.apache.xalan.extensions; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan.xsltc.compiler; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan.xsltc.cmdline.getopt; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan.xsltc.util; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan.processor; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.lib;
>   version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.trace; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan.xsltc.compiler.util; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan.templates; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc;
>   version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.runtime; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xslt;
>   version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.lib.sql; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan.xsltc.runtime.output; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan.xsltc.dom; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.client;
>   version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.cmdline; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xalan.serialize; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.res;
>   version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xml.dtm; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.sax2dtm;
>   version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.dom2dtm; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xml.res; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3;
>   version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.serializer; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xml.serializer.utils; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xml.utils.res; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.utils;
>   version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.functions; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xpath.jaxp; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.patterns;
>   version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.objects; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xpath.res; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath;
>   version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.axes; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xpath.compiler; version="2.7.1",
>   org.apache.xpath.operations; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.domapi;
>   version="2.7.1", org.apache.html.dom; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.wml.dom; version="2.11.0", org.apache.wml;
>   version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.parsers; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.models; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.xni.parser; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.util; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd;
>   version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.dom3.as; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.dv; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp;
>   version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath.regex; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.xni; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.msg;
>   version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.util; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.util; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.dom; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.dom.events;
>   version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xs;
>   version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.io; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.xpointer; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.xinclude; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.xs.datatypes; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.identity; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.models; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.xni.grammars; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.validation; version="2.11.0",
>   org.apache.xml.serialize; version="2.11.0",
>   ,org.apache.karaf.branding,
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax,
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom,
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp,
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni, com.sun.jndi.ldap
>   (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be
>   zero length.)
>
> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be
>   zero length.
>
> at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(ManifestParser.java:744)
>
> at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.(ManifestParser.java:191)
>
> at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.(ExtensionManager.java:221)
>
> at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.(Felix.java:406)
>
> at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory.newFramework(FrameworkFactory.java:28)
>
> at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:310)
>
> at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.main(Main.java:537)
>
> ...

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567419/getting-error-error-parsing-system-bundle-export-statement-when-loading-fuse-es

Comment: I'm running with administrator authority already.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error

After some hit and try found, JAVA_HOME is pointing to jdk 1.5
After changing **JAVA_HOME to jdk1.7**

I am able to successfully restart.

Comment: java 8 is not supported yet